# Can't Connect To MYSQL. Database is created with cpanel and hosted by interserver

Tags: mysql, cpanel

So I created a website in interserver for creating a MYSQL server on there and I don't know how to connect to the server. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: more details please.  something about database, your code to connect etc. this way it is really hard to say anything

Comment: I found the ip address and tried to connect in MySQL workbench. I get 2 errors when i use port (443 forgot where i found it) i get lost connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication packet' error and then when i use the default port of 3306 i get the error "Access denied for user 'sor (my user i created)'@; d4-50-xxx-xx(filled in those because it could lead to my ip).try.wideopenwest.com' (using password: YES). Then is phpmyadmin for the server version it says "10.3.18-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server"